# IconTabBar loses content only on device - cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have a sap.m.IconTabBar containing two sap.m.IconTabFilter controls, each containing a sap.m.Input control. If I enter text in the Input in the first IconTabFilter and then select the other IconTabFilter, then select the first IconTabFilter again, my text has disappeared.

However this is only the case  when I deploy my app to my device - the IconTabBar works fine (the text is retained) on a desktop , or in ripple emulator.

I am using OpenUI5 with Cordova on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2.
A simple hello world app demonstrates this (below). Linked is the same hello world as an APK:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApH-zp9s9-oAgeZa-RHa7Dr3gAMwzQ

When I install the APK on my tablet it has the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <title>HelloWorld</title>

        <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout" 
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>
        <!-- load the mobile lib "sap.m", the layout lib and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var tabBar  = new sap.m.IconTabBar('DG5tabBar',
                     {items: [ 
                       new sap.m.IconTabFilter({icon:"sap-icon://complete",
                                             content:[
                                               new sap.m.Input("Close_Equipment",{})
                                             ] }),
                        new sap.m.IconTabFilter({icon:"sap-icon://wrench" ,
                                             content:[
                                               new sap.m.Input("Close_Equipment1",{})
                                             ]
                                                }),

                             ]})

            var page1 = new sap.m.Page({
                title: "Test Page",
                content : tabBar
            });

            var app = new sap.m.App({
                pages: [page1]
            }).placeAt("content");

        </script>

    </head>
    <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
    </body>
</html>
```